# Cannot use require with packages that have a custom load-path

Tags: init-file, require, load-path

Using `require` with packages that are not in the default `load-path` gives me the error "Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ". However a normal `load` works, but I get strange, seemingly erroneous warnings when using it. Normal packages work fine.

Example:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can also add your `load` invocation here.  The documentation of `require` indicates that it *uses* `load` if the feature is not loaded.  Something isn't adding up.

Comment: Similarly, `load-path` says, "This list is consulted by the ‘require’ function." :)

Comment: @cyberbisson My `load` invocation is just `(load "slime-autoloads")`, instead of the require.